# Get another component input value React js

Tags: reactjs

I have two components one is app component and other one is sidebar component i have been using input field in side bar and i want to get the value of that input field in my app component  on click how this could be possible ?

Comment: on click in textfield or when clicked on AppComponent?

Comment: is the Sidebar child of the App component?

Comment: i have small form in sidebar component want to get the value of input field  which is in that form in the app component on click event and i dont want you use on change event

Comment: sidebar is not a child component

Answer (score 2):

You can try [lifting the state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Create a new component that will contain your two components. In that new component, create a function that you will pass as `props` inside the sidebar component.

```
class ContainerComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            valueThatNeedsToBeShared: '' 
        }
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({valueThatNeedsToBeShared: e.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AppComponent value={this.state.valueThatNeedsToBeShared} />
                <SidebarComponent handleChange={this.handleClick.bind(this)} value={this.state.valueThatNeedsToBeShared} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const SidebarComponent = ({handleChange, value}) => <aside>
    <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
</aside>

const AppComponent = ({value}) => <div>
    value from sidebar: {value}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use onchange event  on input box

Comment: Please explain, why?

Comment: Worked work me ... What if I want to get data from multiple fields like username / password?

Answer (score 0):

In pure react it is possible by adding callback from one component and use it into parent component to change their state and then send input value from parent's state to props of your second component

Comment: Do you have any example ? . i did use the slight different way  define funtion in  app component and triggered in sidebar component in app component i could get this via refs or documetn.getelment by id by puting id on the input field in input box which is in sidebar component

Comment: look into next answer, here it is